# how to get the view that is attached to an animation?

Tags: android, animation, view

here is a pseudoCode

```
1. View myView = new View();
2. Animation myAnimation = new Animation();
3. myView.startAnimation(myAnimation);   // animation attached to the view
4. View myViewCopy = myAnimation.getAttachedView()
```

is there any way I can achieve the step in ***line number 4***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not obviously.  You could write your own classes that extend View and Animation, override the `View.startAnimation()` method to include a copy of the view that gets passed to the animation, and add a getAttachedView method to the animation class?

Answer (score 2):

No. `startAnimation` does not pass any reference to the animation, so the animation doesn't have this information about the view.